# Discrete Mathematics - Graph Theory Question About regular graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a connected graph which is 5- regular
$G = (V,E)$ and it is planar, which of these is a suitable order for this graph (=the number of vertices)

A. 13
B. 11
C. 9
D. 7
E. 8

From what i've looked on the internet, the smallest planar 5 regular connected graph is that huge triangle, which has 12 vertices... and there is not option "12" here.. I would appreciate your help thank you!

Comment: What do you know about the sum of the degrees?

Comment: @quasi So the answer is 8 ? because 8*5 = 40 and 8>=6 , but what about the planar condition?

Comment: The sum of the degrees  = 2|E|

Comment: Planarity is problematic, but the other choices yield an odd sum of degrees, so are not possible.

Comment: Ok I think I got it haha, thankss!

Comment: I'm not sure rhat a _planar_ $5$-regular graph with $8$ vertices exists, so that's the remaining issue to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v$ be the number of vertices, and let $e$ be the number of edges.

Since $G$ is $5$-regular, the sum of the degrees is $5v$.

Hence, since the sum of the degrees is equal to $2e$, it follows that $v$ must be even.

Thus, of multiple choices offered, we can reject all choices except $v=8$.

Suppose $v=8$.$\;$Then $2e=5{\,\cdot\,}8=40$, so $e=20$.

But it's specified that $G$ is connected and planar.

For a connected planar graph the inequality $e\le 3v-6$

$\;\;\;\;\;$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler%27s_formula

must hold, but it fails for $v=8, e=20$.

Hence none of the choices work.